# Segmented Control in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I have used SegmentedControl in my application and given two options in that . I want to show two separate list according to selection of options that means if I select first option , it should show respective list of items and if I select second  option , it should show the other respective list of items.

I want to show some data from database in ListView if I select option first and some other data in listView if I select second option.

Please someone tell me how should I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is two way to achieve this..

1)Use single listview and change datamodel according to selected segment
2)Use diff listview and visible/invisible particular listview according to selected segment..

Here sample code of second way.

```
SegmentedControl {
    id: segmented1
    Option {
        id: option1
        text: "Option 1"
        value: "option1"
        selected: true
    }
    Option {
        id: option2
        text: "Option 2"
        value: "option2"
    }
    onSelectedIndexChanged: {
        var value = segmented1.selectedValue
        console.debug("Selected value: " + value);
       if (value == "option1") {
          listview1.visible = true;
          listview2.visible = false;
       } else if (value == "option2") {
          listview1.visible = false;
          listview2.visible = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks . I will try this . Can you please give me the answer of my other question which I have posted today regarding DataModel.